Not a working screen in the android studio emulator
When I run the android emulator, the screen looks like the phone has a problem with the graphics card.
How can I fix it?
I've tried different versions of androids and phones. I also installed other SDKs. Nothing helped. What can I do?

I have AMD graphic card
